# Clearing directory /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I want to delete many old directories in sqoop compile directory (eg: `/tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/cebe706d23ebb1fd99c1f063ad51ebd7` ) to clean up space.

Does sqoop stores only temporary files in the compile directory `/tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/`?

Will deleting of all directories older than a particular day cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does sqoop stores only temporary files in the compile directory
>   /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/?

It creates jar file out of generated java code for each of your sqoop command (unless you are reusing the jar files). If you are not using parameters such as --jar-file, then you can safely delete those directories.

> Will deleting of all directories older than a particular day cause any
>   issues?

It should not unless you are reusing the jar files using parameters such as --jar-file